# How can I retrieve a JDBC ResultSet as an ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, arraylist, resultset

I'm doing a query to retrieve a large amount of IDs (integers). Instead of iterating millions of times through the ResultSet and copying everything one-by-one to an ArrayList, is there some way to simply retrieve everything as an ArrayList?

I understand that ResultSet is supposed to be iterated because the underlying implementation may be caching stuff, but in my situation I just need all the IDs straight away. I know I can set the FetchSize to a large number, but then I still have to retrieve the IDs one-by-one.

Clarification: the reason I want to do this is performance. Profiling shows me that doing ResultSet.next(), ResultSet.getInt() and ArrayList.add() millions of times takes quite some time. I figure that the database (I'm using H2, which is written in Java) probably has the array or list somewhere in memory, so I'm looking for a way to have it copied to me directly instead of through the ResultSet iterating interface.

Comment: Probably dealing with millions of Integers takes a long time. Do you want an int[] or primitive List-like instead? Probably isn't implemented directly as a int/List because of updates and general tableness.

Comment: int[] or List are both alright. I'm basically just looking for a way to say to the database: forget about caching/lazy loading/etc., just give me the data as quickly as you can :)

Comment: Have a profile and see where the performance issue is. (Oracle does have get column array methods on its ResultSet, IIRC. Not that that matters for H2.)

Answer (score 17):

Using the Apache [DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) library you can easily return a ResultSet as a List of Maps.

```
public List query(String query) {
    List result = null;
    try {
        QueryRunner qrun = new QueryRunner();
        result = (List) qrun.query(connection, query, new MapListHandler());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This won't outperform JDBC itself? Agreed, it looks more convenient, but certainly, it isn't faster...?

Comment: DbUtils is a helper library, so your still using JDBC. Have a look at their site for some of the advantages of using DbUtils. http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/

Comment: I understand, yet the OP seems to have changed the question after you had answered. They were looking for a way to bypass the JDBC API, in order to improve performance...

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what the OP is doing with the IDs.  I would not look to optimize the iteration but try to figure out a way to accomplish the same task so that it doesn't require populating a local data structure with millions of IDs.

Comment: @LukasEder All of the Java database access mechanisms that I know of (JDO/JPA/DBUtils) actually are JDBC under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

Put the code in a method. It's very simple to call methods...

Off the top of my head:

```
public static List<Integer> readInts(
     PreparedStatement statement
) throws SQLException {
     ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
     try {
         assert results.getMetaData().getColumnCount() == 1;

         List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         while (results.next()) {
             ints.add(Integer.valueOf(results.getInt(1)));
         }
         return ints;
     } finally {
         results.close();
     }
}
```

Then just call it as:

```
List<Integer> ids = readInts(myStatemnet);
```

Done.

Comment: this doesn't help performance you are still looping through the data.  I believe he just wants to dump it.

Comment: how would you "dump it" without looping through the data? (The last paragraph of the question was not in the original, btw.)

Answer (score 5):

If your problem is poor performance, tune the statement before executing it with

```
java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize(int)
```

Experiment with 100, 1000, 10000,.. This will avoid unnecessary roundtrips, which may be the cause of the slowness you mentioned.

Also, ArrayList.add() may be slow if it must resize the internal array many times, as it creates a new array and copies all data to there. Try LinkedList instead.

Comment: If you know the fetch size you're going to use, you could also declare in the ArrayList constructor the initial size of its internal array as the same amount.

Comment: @Daddy
From what I understood, the question's author was adding all returned IDs to a single list. This means that your suggestion really does not help unless you create an array with the full size of the result set, not only the fetchsize.

Comment: @Deckard, This question is still has no accepted answer,   Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @monty024 No. Unfortunately, JDBC simply does not expose such a construct so the only possible way to do this would be if some Java-implemented database would explicitly expose it.