# Inserting data from a Select into a list

Tags: java, sql, list, sql-insert

Im creating an SQL statement to Find the free RouteId's from a table, by comparing the booked id's against the list of Id's in the route table.

What i want to be able to do is like at the bottom of the provided code, create an if statement that says if all routes are free then put all those RouteId's into a list.

I can do the rest from there, but how do i get the free routes from the select statement, into a list so i can randomize it?

Is this even possible?

```
 //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="To select all free routes">
           try {
               Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               //load the oracle driver...needs to be in classes folder in jre folder
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
               System.out.println(
                       " Can't find class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               System.exit(1);
           }

       Connection conn3 = null;
       //new connection object
       Statement stmtFreeR = null;
       //new statemnt object
       ResultSet freeRoute = null;
       //new record set object
       try {
           conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.staff.ittralee.ie:1521:orcl",
                   "*", "7*");
           stmtFreeR = conn3.createStatement();
           // create the statement for this connection
           //</editor-fold>

           freeRoute = stmtFreeR.executeQuery(
           "SELECT r.RouteID FROM Route r WHERE RouteID NOT IN(SELECT b.RouteId FROM Booking b)");
           // get the results of select query and store in recordset object
           while (freeRoute.next()) {
               // move to first/next record of recordset
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the answer is " + freeRoute.getString(1));
               // output next record using string format
           }
           //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Error handling for Select Statement">
           freeRoute.close();
           freeRoute = null;
           stmtFreeR.close();
           stmtFreeR = null;
           conn3.close();
           conn3 = null;

       } catch (SQLException e) {
           System.out.println(" A SQL error: " + e.getMessage());

       } finally {
           if (freeRoute != null) {
               try {
                   freeRoute.close();
               } catch (SQLException ignore) {
               }
           }

           if (stmtFreeR != null) {
               try {
                   stmtFreeR.close();
               } catch (SQLException ignore) {
               }
           }

           if (conn3 != null) {
               try {
                   conn3.close();
               } catch (SQLException ignore) {
               }
           }
       }

      // </editor-fold>

       if( /*freeRoute*/ != null) {

           //insert all routes into a list

           //Randomize the list

           //Return random route called RX


       }
```

Comment: Your password is showing ... and connection information.

Comment: Are you after something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642249/how-can-i-retrieve-a-jdbc-resultset-as-an-arraylist

Comment: Indeed it is, Yes something very similar thank you